# Unity trigger problem

Tags: unity

I have been making my first game but I have encountered a small problem. To show the text when you win, you have to go into a block with the OnTriggerEnter line. I cannot get to this block however, because when I put my player (a sphere) as a trigger it just passes through the ground. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the problem that your player always falls through the ground?  And if so, what do triggers have to do with it?  Please clarify exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that my player always falls through the ground and it is to do with triggers because when I don't set the player as a trigger it doesn't fall through the ground but when I do make a trigger it does.

Answer (score 5):

Don't make the player a trigger, make the ending block a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your player as a rigid body, and set the ending block as a trigger. Although you could also put in a box trigger and have it invisible, so when you pass through that area your trigger will allow the end text to appear, and maybe go to a different scene i.e, the menu.